# How to stack LayoutAnchorables vertically in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

This is the layout i am trying to achieve
[image: Example image]

The "Journal" Anchorable is above "Alarms" at start

This is what's inside my DockingManager so far:

```
<xcad:LayoutRoot x:Name="_layoutRoot">
    <xcad:LayoutRoot.LeftSide>
            <xcad:LayoutAnchorSide>
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                        <xcad:LayoutAnchorable ContentId="alarms" Title="Alarms">
                                [...]
                        </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                            <xcad:LayoutAnchorable ContentId="journal" Title="Journal">
                                [...]
                            </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorGroup>
            </xcad:LayoutAnchorSide>
    </xcad:LayoutRoot.LeftSide>
    <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Map">
                            [...]
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
            </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
    </xcad:LayoutPanel>
```